# StratifiedKFold split doesn't seem to work

Tags: scikit-learn, cross-validation

I am trying to perform KFold cross-validation via Keras but due to some reason, the KFold split isn't working.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold

X = train_data[features]
y = train_data['price']

kfold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True)
for train, test in kfold.split(X,y):
    print(X[train])
```

I was actually fitting the model subsequently but that didn't work, so I tried printing the results, which produced the following warning and output.

**Warning:** /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_split.py:672: UserWarning: The least populated class in y has only 1 member, which is less than n_splits=10.
% (min_groups, self.n_splits)), UserWarning)

**Error:** "None of [Int64Index([    0,     1,     2,     3,     4,     5,     6,     7,     9,\n               10,\n            ...\n            39989, 39990, 39991, 39992, 39993, 39994, 39995, 39996, 39997,\n            39998],\n           dtype='int64', length=36000)] are in the [columns]"

Answer (score 0):

The error is self-explanatory:

> Warning:
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_split.py:672:
> UserWarning: The least populated class in y has only 1 member, which
> is less than n_splits=10. % (min_groups, self.n_splits)), UserWarning)

This means that, for the underrepresented class, you have only one sample, hence the stratified split is unable to work.

I recommend that you check your dataset again in order to verify/correct the labels.

Comment: This is obviously the first thing I cross-verified. You can check the screenshot here - https://imgur.com/a/j774mRI. And in case you are wondering the lists 'features' and 'final_featues' are the same.

Answer (score -1):

Using x.iloc[test_index] worked for me

Comment: The answers provided on StackOverflow should be clear and should not be used to advise or seek help from someone else. Let us know your ideas in the comments. If you are not able to leave a comment, try to share the solution of the problem with us.